# SQL Server Update Column Name XML Node

Tags: sql-server, xml

I stored my data in XML format in SQL server, in this way

```xml
**<Column Name="GROSS" DataType="float" Value="939760" />**
```

but somehow one column name (`GROSS`) in my XML data is stored twice, now I want to remove/rename one of them.

Below are screenshots of my database view:

**Table view**

[image: table view screen 1]

**XML view**

[image: XML View screen 2]

This it what I tried, but it only changed the value, it did not rename the column name.

```sql
update Aquara7bc772839.EmpTransaction set TransactionFieldDetails.modify('replace value of (/PayDetails/Column[@Name="LEV_ENCASHRATE"]/@Value)[1] with "796.00"') WHERE Id = 276620;
```

[image: Need to do screen]

I have highlighted my column names in above image link please check 
I want to remove or rename one column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [XML.modify() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type) with a [delete node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/delete-xml-dml) instruction...

```sql
declare @EmpTransaction table (
  Id int not null,
  TransactionFieldDetails xml
);
insert @EmpTransaction values (
  276620,
  N'<PayDetails>
<Column Name="GROSS" DataType="float" Value="939760" />
<Column Name="GROSS" DataType="float" Value="939760" />
</PayDetails>'
);

update @EmpTransaction
set TransactionFieldDetails.modify('delete /PayDetails/Column[@Name="GROSS"][2]')
where Id = 276620;

select * from @EmpTransaction;
```

Which gives you...

```xml
<PayDetails>
  <Column Name="GROSS" DataType="float" Value="939760" />
</PayDetails>
```

Note that the node index is 1-based, i.e.: `Column[@Name="GROSS"][1]` would remove the first GROSS node, `Column[@Name="GROSS"][2]` removes the second GROSS node.

As to how you got two GROSS values in the first place ... whatever created the XML for you probably lists the GROSS column twice.

Comment: That was my first idea too, but - as the OP does not know the reasons - my *"defensive me"* told me to think of *1 or more*. You could run this code several times to catch cases with more than two occurances. Otherwise a third occurance (and any other count) would remain... But it's a good and pragmatic answer, +1 from my side.

Comment: Thanks, @Shnugo. XML.modify() is not my favorite solution - it has the annoying problem that you can only modify one thing per XML instance per update operation.

Comment: That's why I prefere the XML's recreation using XQuery in such cases. But this might be over-acting... (That's why I added some analysis queries to my answer) :-)

Answer (score 0):

For your next question: Please do not poste pictures. Best was, to provide a MCVE (a *stand-alone* sample to reproduce your issue).

You can try something along this:

This is such a *stand-alone* sample

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
(N'<PayDetails>
     <Column Name="blah" DataType="string" Value="Some blah" />
     <Column Name="GROSS" DataType="float" Value="1.1" />
     <Column Name="Another" DataType="string" Value="One more" />
     <Column Name="GROSS" DataType="float" Value="1.2" />
   </PayDetails>')
,(N'<PayDetails>
     <Column Name="blah" DataType="string" Value="Some blah" />
     <Column Name="GROSS" DataType="float" Value="2.0" />
     <Column Name="Another" DataType="string" Value="One more" />
     <Column Name="GROSS" DataType="float" Value="2.0" />
   </PayDetails>');
```

--This query will first check, if there are **different values** for `GROSS` within one XML. This might be a reason to look a bit closer before deleting them.

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.YourXml
FROM @mockupTable t
WHERE t.YourXml.value('count(distinct-values(/PayDetails/Column[@Name="GROSS"]/@Value))','int')>1;
```

--And this statement will return each `<Column>` just once per name (always the first of its kind)

```
UPDATE @mockupTable SET YourXml=YourXml.query(N'
                                               <PayDetails>
                                               {
                                                 for $elmt in distinct-values(/PayDetails/Column/@Name)
                                                 return /PayDetails/Column[@Name=$elmt][1]
                                               }
                                               </PayDetails>
                                               ');
```

--Check the output

```
SELECT * FROM @mockupTable
```

The idea in short:

With the Xpath `/PayDetails/Column[@Name="GROSS"]` we are reducing the observed set to columns, where the attribute `Name` equals `GROSS`. `distinct-values()` is a XQuery-function returning each value in a list just once. So we can use `count()` to check, if there are differing values for `GROSS` within one XML.

The `UPDATE` uses XQuery's FLWOR abilities. We use again `distinct-values` to get all values for `Name` within `<Column>`. Then we return just the first (see the `[1]`) for each name.

### UPDATE: Check for doubled elements

With this query you can run through your whole table to search for any non-unique column name per XML:

```
SELECT t.YourXml.query(N'
                        for $elmt in distinct-values(/PayDetails/Column/@Name)
                        return <NameCount Name="{$elmt}" Count="{count(/PayDetails/Column[@Name=$elmt])}"/>
                        ').query('/NameCount[@Count>1]')
FROM @mockupTable t;
```